# I have a large window that won't resize, how can I fix it?

Tags: screen, window, resize, code-blocks

Codeblocks is taking a lot portion of my screen.I want it to take less screen (preferably upto the red rectangular size i have drawn).Is there any way I can do it ?

I can resize the *height*, but that's not what I want. It seems I cannot change the width though.

[image]

Comment: Can you not resize the window?  What is the problem?

Comment: I can resize it.In this way I can make the length shorter(which I don't want) but the width remain same. @Nmath

Comment: Perhaps this is a limitation of this particular application that it has a minimum width?  Have you exhausted all application settings/preferences from within the application?

Comment: I checked all the settings.There is no option like that

Comment: The minwidth of codeblocks' windows is equivalent to the width of its menu items, so it can't be resized below that.

Comment: @Community What additional information you need to know ?

Comment: @JacobVlijm thanks for all the edits

Answer (score 4, accepted):

##### Minimum window size

Windows have a minimum size, and can't (obviously) be resized below these specifications.

If you are on X (not Wayland) You can see what is the minimum width & hight of a window* : open a terminal and type the command:

```
~$ xprop WM_NORMAL_HINTS
```

Then press <kbd>Return</kbd>. Subsequently, click on the target window.

The output will look like:

```
WM_NORMAL_HINTS(WM_SIZE_HINTS):
        program specified minimum size: 551 by 159
        program specified base size: 0 by 0
        window gravity: NorthWest
```

In the case of Codeblocks, it turns out the window's minwidth is *at least* the width of its menu bar.

**For the exact size & position of a window, we also need to take into account the _NET_FRAME_EXTENTS and _GTK_FRAME_EXTENTS*

Comment: Nice answer. Is there any way to modify those minimum values?

Comment: @Will, I am afraid not, it's often in the code of an application, or if not, defined by the used toolkit.

Comment: I am using ubuntu 20.04 . Run the command and got this output
WM_NORMAL_HINTS(WM_SIZE_HINTS):
  program specified minimum size: 387 by 145
  program specified resize increment: 10 by 22
  program specified base size: 66 by 101
  window gravity: NorthWest 




                                                        I got my answer on your above comments "The minwidth of codeblocks' windows is equivalent to the width of its menu items, so it can't be resized below that" .You can write it as an answer so that I can accept it

Comment: @yoMama33 right, edited it in.

Comment: Well i got an option to disable plugin.I disable some plugin.Thus, Some option from menubar is gone.Hence, I was able to make shorter width

Comment: @yoMama33 Yay! yeah, I thought something like that. I checked, installed codeblocks, my menu is smaller, but still won't resize to below the menu size.

Comment: @JacobVlijm Probably you have not installed contrib plugin .So there are less option in your menu bar compare to me.  Btw Thank you